# how to implement inter-div object movement in three js?

Tags: three.js

How to move (either move or drag n drop) three js objects(for ex. A Cube) from one div to another.
I am making divs by putting all the three js left hand side objects in one div(with one scene and perspective camera) and a different right div(with different div and camera).
[everything else other then the camera and scene is generic]
The problem i am facing is, Raycaster takes camera as input, now if i pass the left hand side camera in raycaster, only left hand side objects intersection is returned, if i pass right hand div camera, only right hand side object's intersection is returned, everything else is returned as 0,0,0.

Any other idea is most welcome.

Comment: You'll need to detect mouseout/over your two view divs and switch the camera

Comment: I changed the camera , but how to change renderer and animate?
(both divs have different renderers and these renderers have camera1 and camera 2 passed as arguments)

Comment: Render both in requestAnimationFrame. In pseudocode:
    animate(){
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
renderer1.render(scene1,camera1);
renderer2.render(scene2,camera2);
}